# Black Screen due to shaders ps_3

Tags: c#, xna, shader

I'm currently using shaders in my game, it's working fine with a nVidia GeForceGT330m but with an ATI 4670 (which supports ps_4.1) I encounter a black screen.

Here is the source of the HLSL effect:

```
struct Explo
{
    float3 position;
    float4 color;
    float power;
    int time;
};
float2 DisplacementScroll;
texture colortexture;

int nb;
Explo explos[5];

float ambient;
float4 ambientColor;

float screenWidth;
float screenHeight;

sampler ColorMap = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <colortexture>;
};

float4 CalculateLight(Explo ex, float4 base, float3 pixelPosition)
{

    float3 direction = ex.position - pixelPosition;
    float distance = 1 / length(ex.position - pixelPosition) * ex.power;
    float amount = max(dot(base, normalize(distance)), 0);

    return base * distance * amount * ex.color * ambient;
}

float4 Explosion(float2 texCoords : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR
{
    //texCoords =  tex2D(NormalMap, DisplacementScroll + texCoords / 3)*0.2 - 0.15;
    float4 base = tex2D(ColorMap, texCoords);

    float3 pixelPosition = float3(screenWidth * (texCoords.x),
                            screenHeight * (texCoords.y),0);

    float4 finalColor = (base * ambientColor * ambient);
    for (int i=0; i<nb; i++)
    {
        finalColor += CalculateLight(explos[i], base, pixelPosition);
    }

    return finalColor;
}

technique KaBoom
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 Explosion();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `Draw()` code as well?  It might be that, that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I remember once I had a similar problem. A shader just didn't work on ATI. The problem was that the vertex and pixel shaders were compiled to different shader models (vs_3_0 and ps_2_0). It worked for NVIDIA, but not for ATI. In your case you're only binding a pixel shader for the pass and who knows what the last vertex shader was.

Granted, this is relevant only if you're dead sure the problem is with the shader and not something else, e.g. your DIPs.

Good luck